# need help in TSQL query that select policy id = 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want a help in query which selects all the data that is having policy_id as 1

the query I am using is

```
select policy_id from Policy_dim where policy_id like '%1';
```

the problem with this is it will select all the data that is having 1 at the last digit eg 21, 31 ,41

the data in the data warehouse for policy id is like

```
 Policy_id
 1
 01
 001
 0001
```

Comment: `select policy_id from Policy_dim where policy_id='1'`  ?

Comment: this will not select data that is having policy_id 01,001,0001

Comment: You could also use `WHERE Right(Policy_ID, 1) = 1` But... @cableload logic is better unless your `Policy_ID` field has non-numeric's hiding out in it.

Comment: You could try`... where convert(int,policy_id)=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select policy_id from Policy_dim where Cast (policy_id as Int) = 1;
```

Comment: @mb1987 If it works then that means that all the data in the column is numeric, in which case why is it stored as a string in the first place?

Comment: I just did it based on the sample data provided.  If alphanumeric, then the OP is going to have to figure out how to strip out trailing numbers (abc123def001 should be just 001)  and then do a cast.